# Setting height 100% in relative positioning

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling to find my answer. Isthre anyway to set the height 100% in relative positioning?

**css**

```
div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Shaxrillo/9pa19Lc3/)

Answer (score 10):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/9pa19Lc3/1/)

For the `height:100%` to work in relative positioning, you need to set the height of `<html>` and `<body>` also to 100%.

If your `<div>` is a child div, then you also need to set the height to 100% for the parent `<div>`s

Add this to your CSS

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Straight forward solution would be to add height the parent that is the `body` as follows .

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shanaka/9pa19Lc3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the parent container must have its height set to 100% as well. In your fiddle's case it will be the `body`

This is because the position is relative so you need to ask what is it set relative to. If you set it to 100% it will become 100% of its nearest parent so if you have a parent container that is less than 100% of the body the relative div will not fill the height of the body.

https://jsfiddle.net/247pao7w/